# How to set background color for a Flex actionscript 3 project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to set the background color of a Flex actionscript 3 project.
I have tried all sorts of things, including

this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" backgroundColor="#FF0000">

</mx:Application>
```

this:

```
SWF(backgroundColor='0x000000', frameRate='30')
```

and this:

```
[SWF(backgroundColor='#000000', frameRate='30')]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there something that is overriding my ability to set this?
I am putting the above lines in my main default runner.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: Hmm....  Is there anything else I can check in Flex?
Where might this other color be coming from?
I checked in my main .html file that is generated after cleaning and building, and I see:


    "bgcolor", "#869ca7",

and

    <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />

Comment: did you modify html-template file?

Comment: yes i did.
i think the problem was that i was making the call before my import directives.  :(
i put it after my import directives (thanks to a friend of mine), and now it works fine.

thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Right click on project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler
2. Add the following into "Additional compiler arguments:"

   -default-background-color #FFFFFF
3. Set backgroundAlpha style property of your application to 0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" backgroundAlpha="0">
 
</mx:Application>
```